conditions on $f$ for: $\omega$ exact $\Leftrightarrow$ $f^*\omega$ exact
In this question it was asked whether, for a (closed) differential form $\omega$, we have that $f^*\omega$ is exact $\rightarrow \omega$ is exact. I can see that this cannot hold in general, but in an answer Daniel Fischer mentioned conditions on $f$ for this to hold. I am wondering what these conditions are (as was also mentioned in the linked question, if $f$ were a diffeomorphism the implication would hold– I am looking for somewhat weaker condtions). 
Would, for example, $f$ being a retraction suffice? I think if it were a deformation retraction it would work via homotopy, but I am not sure in this case. Many thanks.

Every manifold retracts to a point, thus, no. Homotopy-equivalence suffices, of course.

Is this not equivalent to saying that, given a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$, the induced map of de Rham cohomology, $$ f^*: H^k(Y,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^k(X,\mathbb{R}) $$ is injective?
